# Как сверить одну строку со всеми строками из базы.txt, за тем если найдутся совпадения, то записать эту строку в отдельный текстовик?

Tags: python

В общем есть переменная **w2.**
Допустим, что `w2 = "космодром"`, теперь как мне сделать чтобы сравнить  **w2** с каждой строкой из **база.txt** и если найдутся совпадения (хотя-бы одно), то есть даже **"космодромы"** или даже **"космодромовцы"** считается за совпадение, то записать в отдельный текстовик deleted.txt. А если после поиска по всей базе не найдется ни одно совпадение, то записать w2 на w3.

`w3 = w2`

Я не очень то и могу работать с файлами и строками, помогите пожалуйста, хотя-бы идеями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я создал txt файл где написал пару слов, надеюсь все правильно

```
кот
собака
космодром
рыбка
космодромчик
хорек
синичка
космодромодромдром
```

Дальше написал код

```
file_1 = 'base.txt'  #имя файла со словами
file_2 = 'deleted.txt'  #имя файла куда мы запишем совпадения
cosmodrom = 'космодром'  #проверочное слово(должно называться w2
sovpadeniya = []  #список куда мы запишем все слова которые совпадают с космодромом
with open(file_1) as name:  #открываем первый файл
    words = name.readlines() #сохраняем все строки в переменную words
for word in words: #перебираем каждую строку переменной
        if cosmodrom in word:  #проверяет, есть ли в строке космодром
            sovpadeniya.append(word) #если есть, то добавляет эту строку в список
if not sovpadeniya: #если список пусть
    w2 = w3 #я не особо понял что значит w2 = w3, но допустим если совпадений нет
else:  #если список не пуст
    with open(file_2, 'w') as name: #открываем второй файл
        for cosm in sovpadeniya: #для каждой строки в совпадениях
            name.write(cosm)  #записать в файл эту строку
```

Открываю второй файл, там:

```
космодром
космодромчик
космодромодромдром
```

Надеюсь сработает

Answer (score 0):

Вот начни так:

```
import re
text ='В общем есть переменная w2. Допустим, что w2 = "космодром", теперь как мне сделать чтобы сравнить w2 с каждой строкой из база.txt и если найдутся совпадения (хотя-бы одно), то есть даже "космодромы" или даже "космодромовцы" считается за совпадение, то записать в отдельный текстовик deleted.txt. А если после поиска по всей базе не найдется ни одно совпадение, то записать w2 на w3.'
result = re.findall(r'космодром\w*', text)
print(result)
['космодром', 'космодромы', 'космодромовцы']
```

Продолжение

```
import re
text ='В общем есть переменная w2. Допустим, что w2 = "космодром", теперь как мне сделать чтобы сравнить w2 с каждой строкой из база.txt и если найдутся совпадения (хотя-бы одно), то есть даже "космодромы" или даже "космодромовцы" считается за совпадение, то записать в отдельный текстовик deleted.txt. А если после поиска по всей базе не найдется ни одно совпадение, то записать w2 на w3.'
result = re.findall(r'вввсмодром\w*', text)
sumlen = len(result)
if sumlen == 0:
    print("космодром - нет слова")
if sumlen > 0:
    print("космодром - есть слова")
```

Comment: так, что дальше? мне нужно именно узнать как построить структуру If else так, чтобы оно прошлась через всю базу. Так же на месте космодрома может быть абсолютно рандомная строка

Comment: Добавил продолжение.